# nosetests: error: no such option: --with-holmium on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, nose, nosetests

I came across an issue especially on ubuntu 12.04

```
dmitriy@jenkins:~$ nosetests --with-holmium
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py:395: RuntimeWarning: Unable to load plugin holmium = holmium.core:HolmiumNose: six
  RuntimeWarning)
Usage: nosetests [options]

nosetests: error: no such option: --with-holmium
```

Python 2.7.3

Package list:

> dmitriy@jenkins:~$ pip freeze Babel==1.3 GnuPGInterface==0.3.2 Jinja2==2.7.3 Markdown==2.3.1 MarkupSafe==0.23 MySQL-python==1.2.5 PAM==0.4.2 PyMySQL==0.6.1 PyYAML==3.10 Twisted-Core==11.1.0 apt-xapian-index==0.44 argh==0.25.0 argparse==1.2.1 chardet==2.0.1 command-not-found==0.2.44 decorator==3.4.0 docutils==0.11 ecdsa==0.11 fake-factory==0.4.0 ghp-import==0.4.1 guess-language==0.2 holmium.core==0.7.6 httplib2==0.7.2 iotop==0.4.4 ipython==2.0.0 keyring==0.9.2 language-selector==0.1 launchpadlib==1.9.12 lazr.restfulclient==0.12.0 lazr.uri==1.0.3 mkdocs==0.9 nose==1.3.4 oauth==1.0.1 ordereddict==1.1 paramiko==1.13.0 pathtools==0.1.2 pyOpenSSL==0.12 pycrypto==2.6.1 pyserial==2.5 python-apt==0.8.3ubuntu7.2 python-debian==0.1.21ubuntu1 pytz==2013.9 requests==2.3.0 robotframework==2.8.5 robotframework-databaselibrary==0.6 robotframework-faker==0.7 robotframework-selenium2library==1.5.0 robotframework-sshlibrary==2.0.2 selenium==2.42.1 simplejson==2.3.2 six==1.7.3 ufw==0.31.1-1 unattended-upgrades==0.1 wadllib==1.3.0 watchdog==0.7.0 wsgiref==0.1.2 zope.interface==3.6.1

Any ideas how to fix it?